# FormData.has not working in react native application

Tags: node.js, react-native, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

I am working on a project where I need to send image files to a server using a mobile app. After some research, I found that most people use FormData to send images to remote servers so I gave it a go. After many hours of confusion I realized that the FormData object I was sending to the server had no actual data in it, even though I appended a jpeg file into it.

Here's the a segment of the function that handles sending the POST request:

```js
const handleImageChanged = async () =>{
        if (broadImage){

            var formData = new FormData();
        
            formData.append("test", "string")

            console.log(formData.has("test")) //test to see if the value is actually appended
```

The last line of this is code segment throws this error

`TypeError: formData.has is not a function. (In 'formData.has("test")', 'formData.has' is undefined)`